# Node.js & RegEx - Match "assignments" in string

Tags: node.js, regex

Using Node.js and the right regular expression, I need to match any `=` preceded by any string without space and followed by any string which can contain spaces.

I've got a string which looks like that:

```
key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=multiple values
```

It should match `key1=value1`, `key2=value2` and `key3=multiple values`.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work as I'm a RegEx newbie:

```
string.match(/.*=.+?(?=.*=)/g)
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do it: `(\w+)=(.*?)(?=(?: \w+=)|$)`

```js
const string = 'key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=multiple values';
const regex = /(\w+)=(.*?)(?=(?: \w+=)|$)/g

let match;
while((match = regex.exec(string))) {
  const [,key, value] = match;
  console.log(`Key: ${key} - Value: ${value}`)
}
```

Breakdown: `(\w+)=(.*?)(?=(?: \w+=)|$)`

- `(\w+)=` matches the key. Capture group #1
- `(.*?)`. Matches the value. Capture group #2
- `(?=(?: \w+=)|$)` positive look ahead so the value matcher stops at the next key or end of string, without including it in the result.

---

Use `//.exec` instead of `.match` if you want to get all the capture groups when using `g` flag. Otherwise you'll have to split on `=`

```js
const string = 'key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=multiple values';
const regex = /(\w+)=(.*?)(?=(?: \w+=)|$)/g

let matches = string.match(regex) || [];
for(const match of matches) {
  const [key, value] = match.split('=');
  console.log(`Key: ${key} - Value: ${value}`)
}
```

Comment: If you have attribute names potentially containing dashes, such as `some-attribute-name="some value"` you'd need to slightly update the expression `/([-\w]+)=(.*?)(?=(?: [-\w]+=)|$)/g`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent unnecessary backtracking using `.*?`, another option is to use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) with a negative lookahead asserting that the next word does not contain an equals sign.

If you only need to match the key value pairs, you could use:

```
[^ =]+=[^= ]+(?:(?! [^\s=]+=) [^= ]+)*
```

In parts

- `[^ =]+=` Match 1+ times any char except a space or `=`, then match the `=`
- `[^= ]+` Match 1+ times any char except a space or `=`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `[^ =]+=` Match a space, 1+ times any char except a space or `=`, then match the `=`
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `[^= ]+` If the assertion succeeds, match a space and 1+ times any char except a space or `=`
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times to also match a single word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqnDCP/1)

```js
const regex = /[^\s=]+=[^=\s]+(?:(?! [^\s=]+=) [^=\s]+)*/g;
const str = `key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=multiple values`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

---

If you want to have separate keys and values, you could use 2 capturing groups

```
([^ =]+)=([^= ]+(?:(?! [^\s=]+=) [^= ]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/87WB0B/1)

```js
const regex = /([^ =]+)=([^= ]+(?:(?! [^\s=]+=) [^= ]+)*)/g;
const str = `key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=multiple values`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log(`Key: ${m[1]} Value: ${m[2]}`);
}
```